# jQuery won't include in Electron Packager build

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

I installed jQuery for my Electron project with 'npm i jquery', and it works perfectly in the debug mode of Electron.

However, I have begun to package my project, and it only includes jQuery on Windows if I use '--prune=false', and it won't include it for Linux at all.

How can I get Electron Packager to include jQuery in all builds?

Thanks.

Comment: Is jQuery listed in "dependencies" in you package.json file ?

Comment: Yeah, the package.json is here: https://github.com/Adybo123/Meemz/blob/master/package.json

Comment: You could upgrade to electron 2.0.2. I assume electron-packager is installed globally. Try to upgrade it too.

Comment: Sorry, upgrading didn't work. Yeah, electron-packager is installed globally. Is it something to do with the flags in my package-win script?